# googleapi.discovery iam create service account

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Hi I want to use the google api service to create service accounts.

Here is my current code:

```
base_url = f"https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project}/serviceAccounts"
auth = f"?access_token={access_token}"
data = {"accountId": name,
        "serviceAccount": {
            "displayName": name
        }}
Create a service Account
r = requests.post(base_url + auth, json=data)
try:
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.HTTPError:
    if r.status_code != 409:
        raise
```

This works, but it uses the requests package.

I want to use googleapiclient

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
api = build(service, version, credentials=credentials)
```

Then, where do I find information on how to use this api object?
I've tried:

```
api.projects().serviceAccounts.create(name=name).execute()
```

But this does not work, and I don't know how to find what arguments are expected or required.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the GCP IAM API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/iam/v1/python/latest/index.html).
The arguments required and values are documented there.

Comment: You should put the actual answer code/test here, as that link be be changed or moved

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is struggling.

Check out [api explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) to get the format of the request.

For example, If the endpoint is `iam.projects.serviceAccounts.get`

and you need to provide name = "projects/project/serviceAccounts/sa@gsc.googleserviceaccounts.com"

Then your call will look like:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
api = build(service, version, credentials=credentials)

sa = api.projects().serviceAccounts().get(name="projects/project/serviceAccounts/sa@gsc.googleserviceaccounts.com")
```

Hope this helps someone.